# Wait time issue in JMeter Webdriver sampler

Tags: jmeter, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am using JMeter Webdriver sampler for the application UI response time measurement. I am facing issue with the wait function. For example the login page loads between 10 to 120 secs. So I have the following code for the login page in Webdriver sampler for the page load check.

```
var ui=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui) 
var wait=new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,120)
wait.until(ui.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.className('logout-btn-hover')))
```

The issue is even after the page load completely, JMeter is still waiting to perform the next action. This waiting time will reduce if I reduce the 120 secs.But sometimes the application will take 120 secs to load also so I need to keep 120 secs.

I am writing the time to a log file once the sampler completes its action. Because of the wait time issue I am not able to calculate time properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. There are at least 2 errors in your script, it should look something like:

   ```
   var ui=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui) 
   var wait=new ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,120)
   wait.until(ui.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By.className('logout-btn-hover')))
   ```
2. Check out [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) for any suspicious entries, in particular for something like:

   ```
   ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.className: logout-btn-hover (tried for 120 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
   ```
3. [Double check your CSS selector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-selector-tester/bbklnaodgoocmcdejoalmbjihhdkbfon?hl=en)
4. Consider refactoring your code to look for the logout button(?) in a loop with verbose logging for each step. Sample code:

   ```
   var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)

   WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
   WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')
   var start = new Date().getTime()
   var attempt = 1
   while (new Date().getTime() - start < 5000) {
       try {
           var logout = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.className('logout-btn-hover'))
           WDS.log.info('Element found')
           break
       }
       catch (err) {
           WDS.log.info('Attempt # ' + attempt + ', Element not found')
           java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000)
           attempt++
       }
   }
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
   ```

   - Example output when the element is not found:

     [image]
   - Example output when the element is found:

     [image]

Check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) article for more information on using WebDriver sampler in JMeter scripts.